# Use JavaScript/jQuery to manipulate image link url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

SharePoint won't let me set the relative URL I want to use for a link so I'll have to use jQuery/JavaScript instead to manipulate the URL.

Let's say I am at

```
http://subsite.mysite.com/sites/department X/class/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

And on this site I have an image with a link which I want to take me to (skip class in the URL)

```
http://subsite.mysite.com/sites/department X/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

On another site

```
 http://subsite.mysite.com/sites/department Y/class/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

I want to be taken to

```
http://subsite.mysite.com/sites/department Y/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

To do this I was thinking about getting the current path with javascript, split on /, count the length of the array and remove what's between the third and second / from the right (class) and then build the URL again but is this the best way to go or is there a better way to do it?

Cheers

Edit:
maybe I tried to achieve it in a way to difficult way now, it's just that if I set the url using the sharepoint gui with a relative path like ../sitepages/home.aspx or whatever sharepoint overrides this on save and set the full url. However, instead of having to split and stuff I can just change the url to the relative on with javascript.

Comment: You're more likely to be at `http://subsite.mysite.com/sites/department%20X/class/SitePages/Home.aspx`. Also: how do you plan to determine the links (`a` or `img`...) that you want to manipulate?

Comment: Will it always be (literally) *class* or can this part differ?

Comment: Sorry I should have added that, class will also be different. What I want to do is that wherever the script is used it will remove what's between the /department x/ and /sitepages/home.aspx

Comment: If I can get the correct URL I know how to change the url of the link in question, it's only one link on each page and I can give it a class department or something

Answer (score 2):

Use String.replace() with a regex that will match your urls.  For example, this might work for you:

```
link.href = link.href.replace(/\/[^\/]+\/SitePages\//, "/SitePages/");
```